# How to create runtime function which uses object context?

Tags: php, object, dynamic, methods, lambda

I am having a class and I have a dynamically created function (created via "create_function") but I cannot find a way to tell PHP that I want this function to be created for this class only (class function) and because of that the new function cannot access the object properties. Take a look at the following code:

```
class Test {
  private $var=1;

  function __construct() {
      call_user_func(create_function('', 'echo $this->var;'));
  }
}

new Test;
```

This throws error "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\WWW\index.php(7) : runtime-created function on line 1"

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [`runkit_method_add`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php), not `create_function`.

Comment: Note: Requires that you have the runkit PECL extension enabled.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and at my testing enviroinment it seems I don't have the package installed. The thing is that I am writing a plugin and I cannot force the user to have that package, so this is a good solution, but won't work for me. Is there some more generic workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the generic approach. PHP by itself does not give you any way to modify your classes on the run. However, if you describe more specifically what you're trying to achieve, there might be another way to do it without defining methods dynamically.

Comment: @lanzz right.  Most anything that could be done with a dynamically generated function could be done with a sufficiently generic function and class attributes.

Answer (score 3):

As of php 5.4 anonymus function also have `$this` in their context. With a little help from the magic `_call` method it is possible to add a closure as a method to a class, without additional code:

```
class Test
{
  private $var = 1;

  function __construct()
  {
    $this->sayVar = function() { echo $this->var; };
  }

  public function __call( $method, $args )
  {
    if ( property_exists( $this, $method ) ) {
      if ( is_callable( $this->$method ) ) {
        return call_user_func_array( $this->$method, $args );
      }
    }
  }

}

$test = new Test();
$test->sayVar(); // echos 1
```